# Trying to insert and wrap elements

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I have been trying to add a script to my page that will allow me to wrap some code in divs.

What the code looks like.

```
<div class="photoset-grid-basic" >
<div class="photoset-row cols-1">
    <div class="photoset-cell">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

What it needs to look like

```
<div class="photoset-grid-basic" >
<div class="photoset-row cols-1">
    <div class="photoset-cell">
        <div class="image-wrap">
            <div class='social-wrapper'></div>
            <img src="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help have tried loads of things

Comment: _"have tried loads of things"_ Such as?

Comment: pepend, apend, wrapall, before,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.photoset-cell img')
.wrap("<div class='image-wrap'></div>")
.before("<div class='social-wrapper'></div>");
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3FtGD/)

Comment: @Sergio i think both our answers should work, probably OP is missing a DOM ready...

Comment: @StephenWolfe, do you have a live link? do you have jQuery library loaded?

Comment: Right i have made a link live, problem is its not work safe, as the images it loads, ahh maybe I can make the images load blank give the website 20 seconds http://interweb360.co.uk/twitter/hashtag/

Comment: @StephenWolfe, I tried my code on your console and it worked.

Comment: :( I have tired putting the code as the last bit of script and the first neither worked

Comment: @StephenWolfe, can you add my code and try. I don't see my code there.

Comment: @sergio I have added your code to the bottom of the page can you see it now?

Comment: @StephenWolfe, i think your problem is colorbox that loads that html markup after the jquery has run. Try 2 things. 1 - Wrap my code inside this: `setTimeout(funcgion(){ ...my code here...},1000);` if this works, try to use instead the callback function of the colorbox here `callback = function () { and post the code inside it instead.`

Comment: This worked thanks. So i just need to make sure the colour box code loads before the new bit of code!

Comment: @StephenWolfe, great! Yes, check in your code for this `callback = function () {`. I think that function is run after the colorbox is loaded, you could put your code there. Good luck!

Comment: @Sergio Hi I have just tried converting the script in to wordpress and i am going though making changes to the code. on your bit can I change the $(this) to jQuery(document).ready(this)?

Comment: @StephenWolfe, if you are using wordpress you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`. I did not understand what you mean by "`this`" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function(){
    $('.photoset-cell') //Select your target div
             .prepend( "<div class='social-wrapper'></div>" ) //prepend the div to it
             .children().wrapAll('<div class="image-wrap" />'); //Now get all the children and do a wrapAll
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ntNtB/)**

**Update**

Since you have multiple elements you need to do it for each of them.

```
$('.photoset-cell').each(function(){
    $(this).prepend("<div class='social-wrapper'>Test</div>").children().wrapAll('<div class="image-wrap" />');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XLNxP/)**

Comment: @StephenWolfe Did you check the fiddle? is that how it should be"?

Comment: I am trying it at the end of all of my jquery, is this correct because its not adding anything.

Comment: @StephenWolfe Problem is we cannot see your code so can't say much, you could be even having a syntax error before this code executes. Place some console.log in your code and see if it is going there at all. Also make sure it is inside DOM ready wrapper.

Comment: @StephenWolfe There could be many other factors, It might not be event selecting the elements, Did you check the demo link i posted, See if the html structure matches as well. See if you can replicate your issue in the fiddle.

Comment: I have never seen that js fiddle before, looks great but all my code is interacting with a local database. How about I host it and try to replicate it? would that help

Comment: @StephenWolfe Try that but remember that is not encouraged at all in Stack.. :) But post it il take a look .. :)

Comment: I have removed the images!

Comment: @StephenWolfe You need to use $.each.. See this code http://jsfiddle.net/dvGLp/ APply this instead of what is there.